# Comparing a ratio of gamma functions to a simple polynomial

Tags: derivatives, inequality, factorial, gamma-function

I am still struggling to build my intuition as far as reasoning with ratios of gamma functions.

Reasoning with factorials is significantly clearer.

Consider this example.  I would appreciate if anyone could help me to understand how to complete the following with regard to gamma functions.

Let $n > 1$ be any integer.

Clearly:

$$\frac{(2n + 2)!}{(2n)!} = (2n+2)(2n+1) > (n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1$$

So, changing this to a ratio of Gamma functions, the equivalent is:

$$\frac{\Gamma(2n + 3)}{\Gamma(2n+1)} = (2n+2)(2n+1) > (n+1)^2 = n^2+2n+1$$

So far, so good.

My problem comes down to evaluating when a fraction less than 1 gets applied.

For example, consider the value of $\frac{1.25506}{\ln n}$ which is less than $1$ for $n > e^{1.25506}$

While it is easy to figure out any given value and it is straight forward to generate a graph, how do I show that this value is true for $n > 800$ for example.  How would I determine the derivative and show that is increasing (which I suspect it is)?

$$\frac{\Gamma(2n+ 3 - \frac{1.25506}{\ln n})}{\Gamma(2n+1)} > n^2+2n+1$$

In other words, as I leave the safety of factorials, I am at a loss for how to prove or disprove the inequality for all $n > k$ where $k > 800$ for example.

---

Edit:  I think that the inequality may not be true for $\dfrac{5n}{3}$.

I am switching from $\dfrac{5n}{3}$ to $2n$.  I believe that this inequality might be true for a reasonably sized $n$.

I believe that the inequality is true for $n=800$

Comment: Numerical evidence doesn't suggest the inequality is true.

Comment: Thanks Integrand.  I will change it from $\frac{5n}{3}$ to $2n$ which I believe may be true for a lower $n$.  For example, I believe that is true for $n=930$

Comment: I start being fascinated by your problems !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we consider the function
$$f(n)=\log \left(\Gamma \left(2n+3-\frac{a}{\log (n)}\right)\right)-\log
   (\Gamma (2 n+1))-2 \log (n+1)$$

Using Stirling approxiamtion followed by Taylor series, we have
$$f(n)=-\left(\frac{a \log (2)}{\log (n)}+a-2\log (2)\right)+\frac{a^2-5 a \log (n)-2 \log
   ^2(n)}{4 n \log ^2(n)}+\cdots$$

Ignoring the second term leads to a lower bound
$$n_{\text{low}}=2^{-\frac{a}{a-2 \log (2)}}$$ which, for the value of $a$, gives $n_{\text{low}}= 756.660$. Including the second term, Newton method converges immediatly at $n=792.720$.

Using Newton method for $f(n)=0$ with $n_0=n_{\text{low}}$, the iterates are 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 756.6600 \\
 1 & 791.6120 \\
 2 & 792.7187 \\
 3 & 792.7197
\end{array}
\right)$$